# one column split to more column sql server 2008?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

Table name: Table1

```
id   name 
1    1-aaa-14 milan road
2    23-abcde-lsd road
3    2-mnbvcx-welcoome street
```

I want the result like this:

```
Id   name   name1    name2  
1    1      aaa      14 milan road
2    23     abcde    lsd road
3    2      mnbvcx   welcoome street
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This function ought to give you what you need.

```
--Drop Function Dbo.Part
Create Function Dbo.Part
    (@Value Varchar(8000)
    ,@Part Int
    ,@Sep Char(1)='-'
)Returns Varchar(8000)
As Begin
Declare @Start Int
Declare @Finish Int
Set @Start=1
Set @Finish=CharIndex(@Sep,@Value,@Start)
While (@Part>1 And @Finish>0)Begin
    Set @Start=@Finish+1
    Set @Finish=CharIndex(@Sep,@Value,@Start)
    Set @Part=@Part-1
End
If @Part>1 Set @Start=Len(@Value)+1 -- Not found
If @Finish=0 Set @Finish=Len(@Value)+1 -- Last token on line
Return SubString(@Value,@Start,@Finish-@Start)
End
```

Usage:

```
Select ID
      ,Dbo.Part(Name,1,Default)As Name
      ,Dbo.Part(Name,2,Default)As Name1
      ,Dbo.Part(Name,3,Default)As Name2
  From Dbo.Table1
```

It's rather compute-intensive, so if Table1 is very long you ought to write the results to another table, which you could refresh from time to time (perhaps once a day, at night).

Better yet, you could create a trigger, which automatically updates Table2 whenever a change is made to Table1. Assuming that column ID is primary key:

```
Create Table Dbo.Table2(
    ID Int Constraint PK_Table2 Primary Key,
    Name Varchar(8000),
    Name1 Varchar(8000),
    Name2 Varchar(8000))
Create Trigger Trigger_Table1 on Dbo.Table1 After Insert,Update,Delete
As Begin
If (Select Count(*)From Deleted)>0
    Delete From Dbo.Table2 Where ID=(Select ID From Deleted)
If (Select Count(*)From Inserted)>0
    Insert Dbo.Table2(ID, Name, Name1, Name2)
    Select ID
          ,Dbo.Part(Name,1,Default)
          ,Dbo.Part(Name,2,Default)
          ,Dbo.Part(Name,3,Default)
      From Inserted
End
```

Now, do your data manipulation (Insert, Update, Delete) on Table1, but do your Select statements on Table2 instead.

Answer (score 1):

The below solution uses a [recursive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx) [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) for splitting the strings, and [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx) for displaying the parts in their own columns.

```
WITH Table1 (id, name) AS (
  SELECT 1, '1-aaa-14 milan road' UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, '23-abcde-lsd road' UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, '2-mnbvcx-welcoome street'
),
cutpositions AS (
  SELECT
    id, name,
    rownum = 1,
    startpos = 1,  
    nextdash = CHARINDEX('-', name + '-')
  FROM Table1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    id, name,
    rownum + 1,
    nextdash + 1,
    CHARINDEX('-', name + '-', nextdash + 1)
  FROM cutpositions c
  WHERE nextdash < LEN(name)
)
SELECT
  id,
  [1] AS name,
  [2] AS name1,
  [3] AS name2
  /* add more columns here */
FROM (
  SELECT
    id, rownum,
    part = SUBSTRING(name, startpos, nextdash - startpos)
  FROM cutpositions
) s
PIVOT ( MAX(part) FOR rownum IN ([1], [2], [3] /* extend the list here */) ) x
```

Without additional modifications this query can split names consisting of up to 100 parts (that's the default maximum recursion depth, which can be changed), but can only *display* no more than 3 of them. You can easily extend it to however many parts you want it to display, just follow the instructions in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

```
select T.id,
    substring(T.Name, 1, D1.Pos-1) as Name,
    substring(T.Name, D1.Pos+1, D2.Pos-D1.Pos-1) as Name1,
    substring(T.Name, D2.Pos+1, len(T.name)) as Name2
from Table1 as T
  cross apply (select charindex('-', T.Name, 1)) as D1(Pos)
  cross apply (select charindex('-', T.Name, D1.Pos+1)) as D2(Pos)
```

Testing performance of suggested solutions

Setup:

```
create table Table1
(
  id int identity primary key,
  Name varchar(50)
)
go

insert into Table1
select '1-aaa-14 milan road' union all
select '23-abcde-lsd road' union all
select '2-mnbvcx-welcoome street'

go 10000
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I knew it should be possible with CROSS APPLY! I'm still poorly acquainted with the technique. Anyway, my solution is probably faster. :)

Comment: I was a bit too hasty in my assumption as well as in my prior reporting about the results of the comparison. The actual figures I got then were absolutely consistent with yours. Sorry for my being so misleading. And thanks for your testing and for posting the results!

Answer (score 0):

if you always will have 2 dashes, you can do the following by using `PARSENAME`

```
--testing table
CREATE TABLE #test(id INT, NAME VARCHAR(1000))


INSERT #test VALUES(1, '1-aaa-14 milan road')
INSERT #test VALUES(2, '23-abcde-lsd road')
INSERT #test VALUES(3, '2-mnbvcx-welcoome street')

SELECT id,PARSENAME(name,3) AS name,
PARSENAME(name,2) AS name1,
PARSENAME(name,1)AS name2
 FROM (
SELECT id,REPLACE(NAME,'-','.') NAME
FROM #test)x
```

if you have dots in the name column you have to first replace them and then replace them back to dots in the end

example, by using a tilde to substitute the dot

```
 INSERT #test VALUES(3, '5-mnbvcx-welcoome street.')


SELECT id,REPLACE(PARSENAME(name,3),'~','.') AS name,
REPLACE(PARSENAME(name,2),'~','.')  AS name1,
REPLACE(PARSENAME(name,1),'~','.') AS name2
 FROM (
SELECT id,REPLACE(REPLACE(NAME,'.','~'),'-','.') NAME
FROM #test)x
```

Comment: Pretty good, but it only works if you always have 3 or fewer dashes. Oh, and if you don't have any periods (as you point out, you can replace the periods and then restore them). And if you don't have any [square brackets]. And... I'm not sure how ParseName deals with name parts that starts or end with spaces, are you? Generally, the ParseName function wasn't meant for this purpose; it was specifically meant for database object names.

Comment: On my previous comment, I mistakenly pressed "Add Comment" as soon as I typed the first sentance. I immediately edited it to finish my thought. I think that @SQLMenace replied to the first version of my comment, so if it doesn't make sense, it's my fault.

Comment: `SELECT PARSENAME('   .111.222.333',4)` no problem with spaces...btw using case statement you can make it work for less than 4 dashes but in that case your function makes more sense